# android - how to get WebView URL address

Tags: android, eclipse

i am trying to compare URL in if condition

i have following code but its doesn't work simply crash on app loading

```
    i am getting error when i put this code in

            String webUrl = web.getOriginalUrl();
```

here is full code

```
    //loading website
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    setUpWebView();
    web.loadUrl("http://www.domain.com");

    String webUrl = web.getOriginalUrl();

    if (webUrl.equals("http://www.domain.com"))
     {
      //do something
     }
```

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`String webUrl = web.getUrl()`

Comment: could you post logCat with the error?

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this. It will always give you the updated url if url has changed since web view was first loaded.

```
web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
    {
        // url is the current url what are you trying to get.    
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }
});
```